# Configuration members missing from intellisense

Tags: c#, configuration, c#-3.0

I'm currently trying to created a custom ConfigurationSection for my application, however VS2008 is not recognizing any of the members that everyone and the MSDN say are there. The only thing I see is ConfigurationException.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;

namespace CSharpIrcBot
{

    public class ServerSettings : ConfigurationSection
    {

    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a section that has the following data, that I can read and update from the application. These will be user settings.

ServerName, Port (int), RealName, NickName, UserName, ModeMask

The problem isn't that I can't figure out how, its that I am *unable* to even use ConfigurationSection. So my question is... where did it go?

I also seem to be missing ConfigurationManager... It doesn't show up *anywhere* in intellisense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to add a reference to the "System.Configuration" assembly. You can find it in "[windowsfolder]\Microsoft.NET\Framework[framework version]\". It may look like you have the System.Configuration namespace because intellisense shows a few objects in it, but you won't get all the objects until you manually add the reference.

Comment: That was it... I have never had that happen to me before... usually it adds it automagically.

Comment: I had that happen a little while ago - confused me as well.